# Why result from php not same as result from Mysql when use json_encode PHP ?

Tags: php, mysql, json

Why result from php not same as result from Mysql when use `json_encode` PHP ?

This is my html and php code for `index.php` .

```
<?PHP
session_start();
include("connect.php");

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $array = array();

    $text = $_POST["text"];
    $text = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_mysqli,$text);
    $array[] = $text;

    $array = json_encode($array);
    print_r($array);

    mysqli_query($db_mysqli,"INSERT INTO test_1 (xxx)
    VALUES ('$array')");
}
?>


<form class="form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<textarea id="text" name="text"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

When test load `index.php` and fill `先秦兩漢` in to textarea, and then press `ok` button.

You will seee `["\u5148\u79e6\u5169\u6f22"]` on `index.php` page

Then i open mysql and see this result `["u5148u79e6u5169u6f22"]`

I want to know why `\` disappear in mysql ? How can i do for store `\` in mysql ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to choose a utf8_* character set for your table. Text and memo fields will then automatically be stored in UTF-8.

```
`SET COLUMNNAME UTF8`
```

Or Else your canuse below query.

```
`alter table `DBNAME`.`TblName`  Engine=InnoDB checksum=1 comment='' delay_key_write=1 row_format=dynamic charset=utf8 collate=utf8_unicode_ci`
```

Comment: normally column `xxx` is` collation` ==> `utf8_unicode_ci` but still not work, how can i do ?

Comment: Which data type your using ?